# Show that function's inverse is not continuous at a point

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inverse

I have the following problem:

Show a bijective function $f$ where $f'(0)$ is equal to $1$ and where the $f^{-1}(x)$ is not cont. at $f(1)$.

So far, I know that the derivative of an inverse function $f^{-1}(f(x))$ is $(f^{-1})'(f(x))=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(f(x)))}=\frac{1}{f'(x)}$,

and that $f^{-1}$ not being continuous at $f(0)$ would mean that it is not differentiable there either. Don't know where to go from there however.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you substantially changed the request... I think you should leave the question as it was, since it was already answered, and evaluate the answers you were given. Then post another question.

Comment: I agree. Moreover, it seems to me the current question makes no sense.

Comment: Also: the expression you use to connect the derivative of a function and  that of its inverse works if **either** you already know that the inverse function is in fact differentiable, **or** $f$ is *continuously differentiable*.

Answer (score 4):

It's very subtle: Since $f$ is differentiable at $0$, it will be continuous at $0$. But we need a function $f$ that is not continuous on any neighborhood of $0$. Let's try this:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac x2 + \dfrac1{\left[\frac2x\right]}, & x>0 \\ x, & x\le 0.\end{cases}$$
I leave it to you to check that $f$ is injective. Now, $f$ is differentiable at $0$: From the left, the derivative is $1$. From the right, we look at
$$\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(h)}h = \lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{\frac h2+\frac 1{[2/h]}}h = \frac12 + \lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac 1h\frac1{[\frac 2h]}.$$
Now note that
$$\frac 2h-1<\left[\frac 2h\right]\le \frac 2h,$$
so for $0<h\le 2$ we have
$$\frac 1h\frac 1{\frac 2h}\le \frac1h\frac1{\left[\frac 2h\right]} < \frac 1h\frac 1{\frac 2h-1}.$$
Since the left and right quantities approach $1/2$ as $h\to 0^+$, by the squeeze property we have
$$\lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac 1h\frac1{[\frac 2h]}=\frac 12,$$
and, indeed, $f'(0)=1$. Since $f$ has jump discontinuities at $\{1/n: n\in\Bbb N\}$, $f^{-1}$ will not be continuous at $f(0)=0$.

Comment: I do not agree on the fact that $f^{-1}$ is not continuous in $0$. In fact, as you noted, $$\frac2x-1<\left[\frac2x\right]\leq \frac2x.$$
Hence, for $0\leq x <1$
$$x\leq f(x) < \frac{x}2+\frac{x}{2-x}\leq \frac32 x.$$
Therefore for $0\leq x <1$, we have
$$\frac23 x < f^{-1}(x) \leq x,$$
and, by the Squeeze Theorem $f^{-1}(x) \to f(0) = 0$ for $x\to 0$, hence the continuity.

Comment: I believe that the domain of $f^{-1}$ is $(-\infty,0]\cup\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{2n+1}{n^2+n},\frac2n\right]$. Thus, $f^{-1}$ is not defined in any neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: @robjohn Am I correct to state that $f^{-1}$ is in fact injective in its domain? However my observation above should show that this is not a correct example of what required by OP?

Comment: @robjohn The fact that $f^{-1}$ is not defined in a neighborhood of $0$ is not relevant. The function $f^{-1}$ is still continuous at $0$, as dfnu observed.

Comment: I agree with all of this. The OP needs to tell us what definition of continuity the question is assuming. The usual "calculus" definition requires that the domain contain an open set around the point. I could not begin to grok @dfnu's example. :)

Comment: @TedShifrin I'll edit my answer and add some details that should help understand the rationale behind my example.

Answer (score 3):

A few notes first. Suppose, WLOG, that $f(0) = 0$.

If $f$ is continuous and strictly monotonic then it has a continuous inverse. Hence we need $f$ to be **non monotonic or non continuous (or both) in any neighborhood of $0$**.

It is easy to verify that if the function is continuous and non monotonic in some neighborhood of $0$, then (by the Intermediate Value Theorem) injectivity is lost. Thus the function must be **non continuous** in any neighborhood of $0$.

For $f^{-1}$ to be not continuous in $f(0)$, what we need is the existence of $\varepsilon > 0$ such that for any $\delta > 0$ there exists $0<|x|<\delta$ yielding $|f^{-1}(x)|\geq \varepsilon$. If we translate this into a condition on $f$ we obtain the following. There exists $\varepsilon$ such that for any $\delta>0$ there is an $|x|\geq \varepsilon$ such that $0<|f(x)|< \delta$.

In other words, we need the function $f$ to attain values arbitrarily close to $0$ for $x$ belonging to some neighborhood of $\infty$.

First we will construct a function $g(x)$ that satisfies the requirements in the right neighborhood of $0$, and then obtain our function using a reflection.

At this aim, let us start from the identity map $x\mapsto x$ which satisfies the conditions save for the fact that the inverse is indeed continuous in $0$. According to our previous observations, we need to create "holes" in the co-domain (with $0$ as limit point) that will be used as images of "larger" values of $x$. In order to keep differentiability in $0$, we want a function that is bounded for example as follows.
$$h(x) = -x^2+x \leq g(x) \leq x.$$

So if we start, say, from $x= \frac12$, we can decide to replace the identity map with $h\left(\frac12\right) =\frac14.$

Now, of course, to maintain injectivity we have to modifiy the image of $\frac14$. So we let $$g\left(\frac14\right) = h\left(\frac14\right) =  h\circ h\left(\frac12\right) = \frac3{16}.$$

Again this will force us to modify the image of $\frac{3}{16}$. Again we choose to let $$g\left(\frac{3}{16}\right) = h\left(\frac{3}{16}\right) = h\circ h \circ h\left(\frac12\right) = \frac{31}{256}.$$

We can then proceed inductively. This yields
$$g\left(h^{(n)}\left(\frac12\right)\right) = h^{(n+1)}\left(\frac12\right),$$
for $n=0,1,\dots$,
where
$$h^{(n)}(x) =\underbrace{ h\circ h\circ h\cdots \circ h }_{n}(x)$$
for $n>0$ and $h^{(0)}(x) = x$.

Observe that, having started from $\frac12$ we obtained as images rational numbers with some power of $2$ as denominator. See blue dots in the figure below.

[image]

Now that we have created a "hole" in the co-domain, we can fill it, for example by letting
$$g(2) = \frac12.$$
This in turn creates a "hole" in $2$ that can be filled by letting $$g(4) = 2.$$
Proceding further yields, for $n=2,3,\dots$,
$$g\left(2^n\right) = 2^{n-1}.$$
Refer again to the blue dots in the figure below.

[image]

We can now go back to the neighborhoods of $0$ and create another "hole" in $\frac13$, using the same procedure. Note that these further modifications do not interfere with the previous ones since now the images have, as denominator, some power of $3$ (red dots in the first figure above). Again the "hole" will be filled by letting $g(3) = \frac13$, and the process will continue in correspondence with the powers of $3$.

Hence if we let $p_k$, for $k=1,2,\dots$ be the sequence of primes
and, for $x\geq 0$,
$$g(x) =\begin{cases}
h(x) & \left(\mbox{if}\ \ x=h^{(n)}\left(\frac1{p_k}\right),\ \ \mbox{for some}\ k>0\ \mbox{and some}\ n\geq 0\right)\\
\frac1{p_k} & \left(\mbox{if}\ \ x= p_k\ \mbox{for some}\ k>0\right)\\
p_k^{n-1} & \left(\mbox{if}\ \ x=p_k^n,\ \mbox{for some}\ k>0\ \mbox{and some}\ n> 0\right)\\
x & (\mbox{otherwise})
\end{cases} 
$$
we get a function with the desired properties for $x\geq 0$.

Finally let
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
g(x) & (x\geq 0)\\
-g(-x) & (x<0).
\end{cases}
$$
Since $-x^2+x \leq g(x) \leq x$, and $x\leq -g(-x)\leq x^2+x$, we have
$$-x^2+x\leq f(x)\leq x^2+x,$$
wich guarantees, by the Squeeze Theorem, that
$$f'(0) = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}x = 1,$$
as required.

Consider now the null sequences
$$a_k = 2^{-k}$$
and
$$b_k = \frac1{p_k}.$$
We have that $f^{-1}(a_k) \to 0$ whereas $f^{-1}(b_k) = p_k \to \infty$, thus  $$\lim_{x\to 0} f^{-1}(x)$$
is not defined and the inverse function is not continuous in $0$.

---

**EDIT**

One can even think of a function having the required properties and also a **connected and compact domain and range**, as suggested in the plot below.

[image]

The dashed lines represent the parabolas with equation
$$y=-x^2+x$$
and
$$x=y^2-y+1,$$
and the straight line
$$r: \ \ y=1-x.$$
We can exploit the simmetry with respect to $r$ by first defining for $0\leq x\leq \frac12$ the injective function
$$
g_1(x)=
\begin{cases}
h(x) & \left(\mbox{if}\ \ x=h^{(n)}\left(\frac1{p_k}\right),\ \ \mbox{for some}\ k>1\ \mbox{and some}\ n\geq 0\right)\\
x & (\mbox{otherwise}).
\end{cases}
$$
Then, for $0\leq x \leq 1$,
$$
g(x)=\
\begin{cases}
g_1(x) & \left(0\leq x\leq \frac12\right)\\
\frac1{p_k} & \left(\mbox{if}\ \ x=1-\frac1{p_k},\ \ \mbox{for some} \ k>1\right)\\
1-g_1^{-1}(1-x) & (\mbox{otherwise}).
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Your inequality on $f$ is messed up, and offhand I don’t see why (the correct version) is true.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for your observations. I cleaned up the first part of the discussion (the part related to monotonicity was not correct and requires some other thoughts on my side), explained in much greater detail the motivations behind my construction, corrected the inequality, and explained why it works.

Comment: @TedShifrin I now added also a variation of the same concept, allowing to construct a function with the same properties, plus a compact (and still connected) domain and range.